# How to get values of Year,Month and Day from String with help of Regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I am using Android Studio, and I have a `date` string which could be like this

```
2018/1/7
2018/10/7
2018/1/30
```

And I want to use Regex to extract Year, Month and day from it.
I have this code:

```
int[] getAlarmTimeArray() {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})\\/(\\d{1,2})\\/(\\d{1,2})").matcher(date);
        return new int[]{
                         Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)),
                         Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)), 
                         Integer.parseInt(m.group(3))};
    }
```

This code always produces:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
```

I am sure that the `date` delivered to the function is good, and I also tried some other patterns, but nothing.

```
"(\\d{4})\/(\\d{1,2})\/(\\d{1,2})"

"(\\d{4})/(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})"
```

I tried the first pattern on [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OOO26v/1/) and it works fine.

I am not that good using Regex so please help me.

Comment: "And I want to use Regex to extract Year, Month and day from it" -- why not use `SimpleDateFormat` or some other date parser?

Comment: @CommonsWare It seemed more efficient and less code

Comment: Problem with using a regular expression is that it cannot handle date semantics. So you won't be able to detect invalid dates; maybe that's not an actual problem in your case (if the strings are results of marshaling date objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--)

```
if (m.find()) {
    return new int[]{
        Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)),
        Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)),
        Integer.parseInt(m.group(3))
    };
} else {
    //return default value or throw an exception
}
```

---

**Solution 2**

There are another way, where you can use split, for example :

```
String date = "2018/1/7";
String[] split = date.split("/");

return new int[]{
    Integer.parseInt(split[0]),
    Integer.parseInt(split[1]),
    Integer.parseInt(split[1])
}
```

---

**Solution 3**

If you are using Java 8, You can use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library :

```
String date = "2018/1/7".replaceAll("/(\\d)/(\\d)$", "/0$1/0$2");

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, format);

return new int[]{
    localDate.getYear(),
    localDate.getMonthValue(),
    localDate.getDayOfMonth()
}
```

Or without `DateTimeFormatter` you can use :

```
String date = "2018/1/7".replaceAll("/(\\d)/(\\d)$", "-0$1-0$2");
//----------------------------------------------------^---^
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
```

Comment: That won't make it. In my app, if the function is called, it means that the matcher must find a much. There is no default value.

Comment: the key word in this answer is to use find() without it your code will not work just if you use another way

Comment: check my edit @hiddeneyes02

Comment: Great, two first solutions worked. Third one requires API 26. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not Regex solution, but in your scenario, it will give you expected output. This solution works on Java 8+.

```
 String date = "2017/06/12";
 int[] arr = Arrays.stream(date.split ("/")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Basically, given `String` will be split into `String` array on `/` and then `String` array converted to `int` array.

In Java 7 or earlier version :

```
 String date = "2017/06/12";
 String[] str = date.split("/");

 return new int[]{
    Integer.parseInt(str[0]),
    Integer.parseInt(str[1]),
    Integer.parseInt(str[2])
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not supported for API less than 24

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 I didn't get you not supported. what error are you getting ??